# Workaround to Install Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel RST systems

Tags: grub2, uefi, raid, ahci, rst

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 in my Dell G5 which has 2 drives. One with Windows 10 on it (256 GB) and another one with 1 TB capacity.

I shrunk the volume of 1 TB by 150 GB and tried to install there.

But Ubuntu installer didn't allow me as I got a dialog after the Keyboard setting said "Turn Off RST" with the message

> This computer uses Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology). You need to
>   turn off RST before installing Ubuntu. For instructions, open this
>   page: help.ubuntu.com/rst

If I make any changes in the BIOS setting, like changing the Intel controller from RAID to AHCI, Windows won't boot and goes into System Recovery.

I didn't have this issue when installing 18.04. While creating the partitions, you need to create a EFI partition with 200 - 500 MB with the usual steps and the installation will be completed succesfully.

On restarting, you will not be getting the GRUB but instead Ubuntu will boot by default. If you need to boot Windows, you will have to go to the BIOS and choose from the UEFI boot option each time.

Once 18.04 installation is complete, you can upgrade it to 20.04.

After upgrading I installed the KDE desktop and at the login screen I chose the "Ubuntu on Wayland" option.

After doing these 2 things, I lost the new features of 20.04 like the Ubuntu boot screen with Dell logo and the power off/log out blur effect screen. Not sure how to get that back.

Comment: See new documentation and discussion at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Comment: I have the same problem. I just have one question. When you upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 , apart from the missing things in GUI was there any major changes ?

Answer (score 58):

You've got a single HDD/SSD set up in RAID (RST) mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your HDD/SSD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

You don't need to reinstall Windows.

Below, you'll find two different ways to solve this problem. **Some users found Choice #2 to be easier.**

**Important: Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!**

<strike>**Choice #1:** Looking at [this article](https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/)  will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows.</strike>

**Important: Some users reported to be completely unable to boot Windows after using Choice #1, without a full restore**

- Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
- Open `Device Manager`
- Expand `Storage Controllers` and identify the `Intel SATA RAID Controller`
- View properties of the identified controller
- On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
- Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
- Uncheck `Show compatible hardware`
- Select `Microsoft` as manufacturer
- Select `Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller` as model #
- Accept that `Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible`
- Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
- Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

**Choice #2:** See [here](http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/).

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
- Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`

  - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`

  - If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Comment: Thanks very much. I already tried the Choice #2. But my windows didn't boot after that it was going into System Recovery option. Then I reverted back the changes. I will try the Choice #1. I'm now used to live without the GRUB using the BIOS to get into Windows when needed.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned, if I change anything with the BIOS, the windows is going into System recovery and not booting. Now as I have already installed 20.04 as default OS and choose Windows from the BIOS Boot options when needed. I do not want to disturb it and lose my files. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I created an account just to thank you, nothing worked but this solution worked the first time!!!

Comment: @HenryLeBerre Thank you for the kind feedback!

Comment: Thanks! Choice #2 worked for me! Although making 2 answers out of this would be better for voting.

Comment: @heynnema I've followed option 1 and have currently bricked my computer because my BIOS didn't have the option to use AHCI - only RAID shows as an option. I also can't login to windows  10 anymore. Is there a way to reset option 1 so I can log back into windows 10? Thanks.

Comment: @ClickUpvote I'm sorry to hear about your troubles. I'm not a Windows expert, but I believe that if you hold down the SHIFT key during Windows boot, it'll present you with some options to repair Windows. Otherwise you may need to boot to a Windows installer CD/DVD to do it.

Comment: #2 worked for me. #1 bricked my laptop.

Comment: If using method #2, is there no need of changing REGISTRY KEYS in Windows, like it is indicated in this tutorial? https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Comment: @MarcosSaito No need to change registry keys via method #2. The link you provided is just another (more complicated) way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Should i again re enable RST after installing Ubuntu?

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson No. Leave is set to AHCI.

Comment: @heynnema , And what about the safe boot? Should I re enable those again?

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson No. If you followed the instructions, safeboot would be reset.

Comment: +1: Choice #2 worked well for me :-)

Comment: About to try Option 2. It's getting good feedback so hopefully everything goes well! :)

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks! Although I seem to be having trouble opening my computer's BIOS menu now. Any ideas why that might be happening. My computer seems to be functioning normally....

Comment: @pigeonburger Can you get to the BIOS from the GRUB menu?

Comment: @heynnema It's all good now - I just rebooted. Thanks

Comment: @heynnema would recommend that you add a disclaimer in your answer that this method would not work if one has a NVMe SSD as NVMe is not backward compatible with AHCI. This may save a lot of paing and confusion for many a users.

Comment: @Shrenik I haven't heard that. Do you have a link that might describe this?

Comment: @heynnema 1. From personal experience.
2. Herein - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347/4
3. https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/nvme-drive-booting-in-ahci-mode.2500796/. 
Searching for 'NVMe compatibility with AHCI' will give you ample results.

Comment: Can anyone confirm solution #2 works flawlessly with an NVMe SSD?  Looking to do this on Dell 9500 on a second drive but really don't want to brick the first (Windows) drive.

Comment: @Curtis Read the previous comments from Shrenik.

Comment: Choice #2 worked flawlessly for me to set to AHCI. I have dual NVMe drives (Dell XPS 15 9500), one for Windows and one for Ubuntu 20.04.  First drive is Dell OEM, second drive is Samsung 970 EVO Plus (1TB). I did turn off encryption and fast boot prior to changing. Thank you!

Comment: @Curtis Good news! Thanks for the update.

Comment: I'm running a Dell XPS 15 7590, with a Micron 1TB NVMe. Option 2 has worked fine for me so far - dual booting between Win10 and Mint 20.

Comment: I have Dell XPS 15 2-in-1 9575, with a 1TB NVMe. Option 2 has worked fine for me so far - dual boot between Win10 and Manjaro (although `ctfmon.exe` in safeboot was crashing constantly).

Comment: There is a much easier way using the msconfig as shown in this video: https://youtu.be/AIhWnmLx51A

Comment: you are the master of puppets :) +1 - 2 option worked like a charm

Comment: After I changed the mode to AHCI, Windows didn't boot. So I tried to boot again and it booted successfully in safe mode. To sum up, it required to boot twice. Thanks.

Comment: #2 worked for me too and I confirm that you can type Win+R and then run **msconfig** to set the next boot to "Safe mode - Minimal" and after you reboot you can run **msconfig** again to revert the change. No need to run bcdedit on the command line unless you really want to.