# Ubuntu only sensing 13 GB of 1TB SSD after trying to install over damaged Windows

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd

I am quite new to Linux and Ubuntu. I recently ran into a pretty troublesome problem and was wondering if anybody could help.

At first, I wanted to dual-boot with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows. However, I ran into a problem as I was trying to install it. I got this error message:

> This computer uses Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology). You need to turn off RST before installing Ubuntu. For instructions, open this page: help.ubuntu.com/rst

I tried following the first solution on [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems). However, when I booted to Windows, it immediately went into recovery mode. I switched the SATA controller and tried all of the recovery options, but it looked like my Windows was gone.

I have a Windows bootable CD, so I thought I'd just install Ubuntu over everything. I turned off RST and went to install it, but after installing it I realized that it only partitioned out 13.6 GB of my 1 TB disk. I had thought it would wipe the disk completely and install Ubuntu.

I tried installing it again but it only seemed to be able to sense those 13.6 GB. Does anybody know what happened and if I can fix it? Nothing I've tried seems to work. Thank you.

Editing with output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`

```
NAME    FSTYPE           SIZE MOUNTPOINT                             LABEL
loop0   squashfs        28.9M /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/15               
loop1   squashfs          97M /snap/core/9289                        
loop2   squashfs       161.4M /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128              
loop3   squashfs       255.6M /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36               
loop4   squashfs        62.1M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506           
loop5   squashfs          55M /snap/core18/1754                      
loop6   squashfs        43.2M /snap/snap-store/415                   
loop7   squashfs        62.9M /snap/rambox/13                        
loop8   squashfs       240.8M /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24               
loop9   squashfs          55M /snap/core18/1705                      
loop10  squashfs       142.4M /snap/opera/78                         
loop11  squashfs        49.8M /snap/snap-store/467                   
loop12  squashfs       290.6M /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/ 
loop13  squashfs       140.6M /snap/opera/79                         
loop14  squashfs        19.8M /snap/okular/98                        
loop15  squashfs        27.1M /snap/snapd/7264                       
loop16  squashfs        29.8M /snap/snapd/8140                       
sda     isw_raid_membe 931.5G                                        
├─sda1  vfat             650M                                        ESP
├─sda2                   128M                                        
├─sda3  ntfs           917.4G                                        OS
├─sda4  ntfs             990M                                        WINRETOOLS
├─sda5  ntfs            11.3G                                        Image
└─sda6  ntfs             1.1G                                        DELLSUPPORT
sr0                     1024M                                        
nvme0n1                 13.4G                                        
├─nvme0n1p1
│       vfat             512M /boot/efi                              
└─nvme0n1p2
        ext4            12.9G /
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`.  Retain all line breaks and format the answer as `code` by putting four spaces before each line.

Comment: @Nmath I've done as you said. I see that the storage is _somewhere_ now, so that's at least a bit comforting. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: it looks like the disk labeled as `sda` is 1TB and also looks like Windows was, and is still, installed there, along with several other partitions.  Is there anything on these disks that you want to keep that hasn't been backed up?  If you want to wipe everything, I suggest doing this prior to the installation.  You can boot Ubuntu live from the installation media (the "Try Ubuntu" option).  Then use the application "Disks" to format your hard drive(s).   Leave them empty, freshly formatted, then you can reboot and install Ubuntu and there won't be any stubborn partitions in your way.

Comment: @Nmath Awesome! I'll try that and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your response. I really am pretty new to Linux and computers in general, so I appreciate the help.