# Installing Ubuntu stopped at Rapid Storage Technology override by windows 10

Tags: boot

I have a boot able USB disc and I can start installation on my computer but Windows stops at Rapid storage technology Override with the order to "stop installation and restart", not an error message.

Computer: HP Envy 64 desktop model TEGY1-0250X1
OS:       Windows 10 1909 home Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Also. Ubuntu does not ask what type installation i want. I want to remove windows.

If Ubuntu will take charge of my computer and install I will pay a reasonable amount. I am 77 years-old and doing this is difficult.

Comment: Don't remove Windows. You'll need it to do BIOS/firmware updates, etc. To install Ubuntu, see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems/1233644#1233644

Comment: When installing Ubuntu, choose the "Install along side of Windows" option, to create a dual-boot environment.