# Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel RST systems - implications of running bcdedit command while safe boot has already been activated through msconfig

Tags: grub2, uefi, raid, ahci, rst

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 on my Acer computer. While trying to install Ubuntu, I was prompted with a warning about Intel's RST needing to be turned off. Following [Choice #2 in heynnema's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems), I learned that I should:

> (run in command prompt) `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
>
> (in BIOS) `Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI` from either IDE or RAID

Before trying anything, I played a little bit with the BIOS to see how that could be done. Had to do some research and found [this answer](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/606504/changing-sata-mode-on-acer-aspire-5), which suggests:

> a) access windows and then press `windows + r and type msconfig`. Then,
> go to system boot and activate safe boot. Then restart windows;
>
> b) then access the BIOS, go to the main tab, press `ctrl + s` and change
> the sata mode to ahci.

That works, the option to change to AHCI is there. I haven't tried it yet because **I was wondering if the bcdedit command proposed by heynnema does the same as following a) and activating safe boot through msconfig**.

I thought doing both - in case they're similar commands - could cause me problems.

Comment: They do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Am I right to assume that after changing SATA to AHCI and booting in secure mode, if I go to msconfig and **deactivate** safe boot is the equivalent to running `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`? (2) Should I expect Windows to work normally after this process to get RST turned off?

Comment: 1) Should be... but I wouldn't recommend deviating from the written procedure too much. And you want to turn off FAST BOOT and HIBERNATION in Windows, and SECURE BOOT in your BIOS. 2) Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

## RST

Recommend following the instructions (Choice #2) found [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems) without deviation.

## In Windows

To disable FAST BOOT and HIBERNATION...

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`

If you wish to check your C: drive, and others...

- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

## In BIOS

- disable SECURE BOOT

Comment: (1) Only after these steps have been taken, in this order, should I proceed with the Ubuntu installation? (2) Excuse my ignorance; why is it necessary to disable fast boot, hibernation and secure boot to be able to install Ubuntu alongside Windows (in a machine with  Intel's RST)? (3) Should any of these changes be reverted after Ubuntu has been installed?

Comment: @kiabbo 1) Best way to do it. 2) To be able to install Ubuntu, and make it run reliably without problems from Windows. 3) No.

Comment: For future reference: the above worked perfectly! On some computers, to be able to disable Secure Boot, a supervisor password should be set in BIOS. Also, to change to AHCI, I had to follow letter b) in my question. Might be useful for someone else.