# Correct way to change from RST to AHCI and implications

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo, ahci, rst

today I tried to install ubuntu on my computer (**Lenovo Idea Pad Intel Core i7-8565U BIOS-Modus UEFI**). I opted for a dual boot configuration.
During the installation I received a message saying:

> This computer uses Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology). You need to
> deactivate RST before installing Ubuntu. For instructions, open this
> page: help.ubuntu.com/rst.

So I did, I entered the settings by pressing the F2 key during startup and then I switched from "**RST mode**" to "**AHCI mode**", as shown [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2JGC.jpg).
Ubuntu was then installed without problems. Now I have three questions. But first I would like to point out that I am not an expert, so I apologize if they may seem trivial or stupid.

1. What are the implications of this change of settings? Is efficiency affected in any way?
2. Every time I start the pc I have to select the operating system I want to use. If I use windows I am forced to use the **RST** configuration, unlike Ubuntu which only starts with the **AHCI** configuration. Every time I start up I have to change the settings manually or is there a way to automate the procedure?
3. This is perhaps the most important question. Initially, when Ubuntu asked me to disable **RST** mode, was it the right procedure to disable it manually? Without changing anything else? I ask this because it seems "too easy" honestly and I have the feeling I missed a few steps.

Thank you in advance for your answers, I also apologize for the grammar and/or for any mistakes but English is not my mother language.

Comment: You need to install AHCI drivers into Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 Some tech details, but says essentially no difference: https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571