# How to install Ubuntu 20.04 in laptop with RST

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, usb-installation, rst

I'm trying to full install Ubuntu 20.04 on my new laptop, but I get this error `turn Off RST`. I want to single boot Ubuntu. or is it possible to install the Ubuntu from other unit system first and put it back to my laptop?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/

Comment: @kortewegdevries this problem is for dual-booting only, this question might work ? for full installation not on dual-booting?