# Dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

On a PCLaptops computer (AMD Ryzen 5, Nvidia Geforce GTX) with Windows 10 installed I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual boot. I restart the PC and select the USB drive containing Ubuntu 20.04 as the boot device. After Checking the disks and getting 'No errors found' I get to the second screen of the Install where 'Normal installation' & 'Download updates' are already selected. I can get no further than this. The screen does not scroll. Selecting 'Install third-party software' gives me the opportunity to 'Configure Secure Boot' but either selecting this or not I can find no way to continue. The screen just remains there at this point. Enter does nothing except toggle the 'Install third party software' option once it is selected.
Is this a hardware or software issue?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? And if SSD, updated its firmware? Is Widnwos fast start up off. Use Windows to shrink NTFS to make unallocated space for Ubuntu. Often better to have UEFI Secure Boot off. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: The PC is a 2020 model and I have done nothing with UEFI. It came with a 500 GB SSD and I have no knowledge of any updates to the firmware. The OS Support is UEFI and Secure boot is active. But with Ubuntu 20.04 64bit Secure Boot is supported as is UEFI.

Comment: . I don't know about fast startup but Wake from Sleep (S3) with USB is enabled. I did shrink the WIndows partition to give me 30000 Meg free to install Ubuntu. But, I get as far as selecting how to install Ubuntu and cannot get past that whether I select Secure Boot or ignore it. That screen just stays there, no way to continue.

Comment: Is UEFI settings for drives Intel RST or RAID? You need to install AHCI drivers into Windows and change UEFI to AHCI. Vendor support site should have UEFI updates. SSD may be at system vendor or SSD vendors support site.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 You also need Safe Boot or nomodeset boot parameter. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: As I understand RST is Intel chip only - mine is AMD. NeMe RAID is set to disable on the American Megatrends Bios. I need to check with Vendor (PCLaptops) about AHCI drivers. What do you mean with your SSD statement. whether there are updates to the SSD driver?

Comment: New SSD have firmware updates. Many, even brand new, need that update to work or work well. Some vendors have updates and/or update software at their support site. My Samsung SSD has firmware updates on its support site which I have to download and install via an bootable ISO (no Windows). Samsungs update application mostly works with Windows. Many have installed with Secure Boot, but proprietary drivers make it more difficult. Perhaps some settings in your system are also turned off when Secure Boot is off?

Answer (score 1):

By disabling Secure Boot in the Bios, installation of Ubuntu 20.04 completed successfully. The comments about the latest Ubuntu software being compatible with Secure Boot must be erroneous.
Thanks to oldfred for all his help and suggestions.