# Trying to make window dual boot: Why is the installer not showing during Ubuntu installation -- RAID 0 drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, raid

I am stuck trying to dual boot to Ubuntu on my Windows computer. The partition is not showing up during the Linux installation. I believe that it has something to do with drives in RAID-0 configuration. But I have no idea how to fix this.

## DETAIL:

I partitioned drive using WINDOW-10's "diskmgmt.msc" and then changed the formatting to "ext4" using "AOMEI Partition Assistant 8.10".

On window side, the disk partitions and other relevant properties are shown in the following image:
[image: Disk partitions on Window side]

While installing, I am struck at "Installation type" window. The screen shot is shown below.
[image: "Installation type" window during Linux installation]

I ran the live version of Ubuntu and then ran genome-disk. I can see two drives. 128 GB drive is my bootable USB. I do not know what 2.1 GB Loop drive is. I am attaching the screen shot:
[image: genome-disk window]

Comment: I see no free space. Have you made room for Ubuntu?  Don't use *Windows* to create partitions for Ubuntu.  You need unallocated free space. The Ubuntu installer will make a partition for you.

Comment: You also need fast start up off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
 and probably UEFI update which may reset UEFI settings like AHCI. Only if two drive RAID 0 should you not change drives to AHCI, but first install AHCI drivers into Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347