# Lubuntu not able to detect ssd

Tags: lubuntu, ssd

I bought a new asus laptop which has 128 gb windows 10 pre installed and has 1TB of harddisk.
I want to install windows 10 on hdd and Lubuntu on ssd but while doing it show it cannot detect ssd so I am stuck in between

Comment: There maybe an RST RAID configured for Windows. In this case you won't see a separate SSD. Nayway there is no information to tell anything. What does `sudo parted -l` show. Add it to the question.

Comment: It only shows 1000gb drive

Comment: What model Asus? Have you updated UEFI, updated SSD firmware? And changed from RST to AHCI? You have to first install AHCI drivers into Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

Comment: Then SSD may be used only for cache. I don't thing you can change it.

Comment: Its. Solved I justed switched the sata configuration to AHCI the installation then detected ssd