# Problem while changing the SATA mode to AHCI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, raid, bios

I recently bought a new laptop, an Acer Nitro 5, the latest model with 10th Generation Intel i7 processor, and an Nvidia GTX card (normal drill).

I had encountered a problem where Ubuntu gives me the Intel RST disabling error, for which there are various forums that enlist various methods to help me with that.

All of them involved one step in common - changing the SATA mode to AHCI. Right now I face the issue where my BIOS does not allow me to change my SATA mode configuration. It currently shows the option "Optane with RAID", which I am unable to change in any possible way.

I also tried changing to supervisor mode, which enabled me to change the fast boot option. This didn't help me change the SATA option too.

If someone could help me with how do I proceed with this, it would be great. All my work is stalled since I cannot install Linux in any way. I have attached the BIOS images to make sure there is no other minor obstacle coming my way.

This is what is shown

[image: This is what is shown]

2nd tab

[image: The second tab]

3rd tab

[image: 3rd tab]

4th tab

[image: 4th tab]

5th tab

[image: 5th tab]

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? Is yours similar to this? Acer Nitro 7 Missing AHCI mode Ctrl + S in UEFI
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429951&p=13900969#post13900969

Comment: @oldfred that reads like an answer to me ;-)

Comment: Do not know if it works for Acer 5?

Comment: @oldfred I should check it out in a few minutes, and get back with a reply to this thread. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: New BIOS revisions don't allow to change the SATA mode brcause people break their Windows installations and complain. You can use Ubuntu in RST mode, the only problem is dual boot.

Comment: @oldfred The link you have provided does the work! I now am running Ubuntu without any issues absolutely! Thank you for your help. I shall add an answer to this myself with your link in it. Cheers!

Comment: If dual booting with Windows you need to install Windows AHCI drivers. You can temporarily change back to RST, install drivers and then back to AHCI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

Comment: Hey @oldfred , I have dual booted ubuntu with windows flawlessly given your technique. I think the drivers might have been installed already on thw machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very thankful for @oldfred for helping me with an old link. I now have Ubuntu up and running on my machine. The link is given below here -

[Acer Nitro 7: BIOS Main menu SATA Mode Missing](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429951&p=13900969#post13900969)

Now I can finally have a peaceful night's sleep.