# RST error on Dual M.2 NVMe Boot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10, rst, nitro

I got an Acer Nitro 5 Laptop (AN515-54) recently, it came with an M.2 NVMe drive with Windows 10 pre-installed on it. Since it has Dual-M.2 + 1x 2.5" SATA support I wanted to have a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot. So, I installed another M.2 NVMe SSD on the other slot, set up a bootable USB with Ubuntu (20.04.2.0) and tried to install it.

When i was trying to install Ubuntu i got a message saying I needed to disable RST in order to install Ubuntu, but Ubuntu's help page says it may cause Windows HDD to be unable to boot. Is there a way I can achieve that Dual boot config without destroying my Windows setup?

Comment: You just have to install the Windows AHCI drivers first into Windows. Or boot in recovery mode to install AHCI drivers. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems  But if you do a safe boot first, then boot to BIOS and change to AHCI and finally boot normally, it works
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

Comment: @oldfred Thanks a lot, it was a little bit different because of my Laptop's boot menu  (I had to press Ctrl + S to make the "SATA operation mode" option appear) but it worked.

Comment: Acer Nitro 5 Missing AHCI mode Ctrl + S in UEFI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301872/problem-while-changing-the-sata-mode-to-ahci?noredirect=1#comment2213148_1301872
[SOLVED]Acer Nitro 5 (with Ryzen 7 2700U, RX 560X) Ubuntu 18.10  
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413504 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412117 &
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/555251/unable-to-install-ubuntu-in-my-nitro-an512-42