# install ubuntu 18.04 in acer nitro 5

Tags: boot, system-installation, acer

I bought acer Nitro 5 but I cant install ubuntu 18.04

could any one help me why I cant

I bought extra CD and also I cant,, I want it in my work

Comment: You've provided few specific details; what Ubuntu 18.04 product are you trying to install?  (ie. server? desktop? flavor?) did you download the ISO? validate the ISO? write the ISO to media? or what did you actually do and where did you get stuck? or have issues you need help with?

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 18.04 will be supported until April 2023. You can use Ubuntu 22.04 instead, it will be supported until 2027.

Comment: I download (ubuntu-18.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso).. I don't know much about ubuntu

Comment: In UEFI settings, you may need this: Acer Nitro 5 Missing AHCI mode Ctrl + S in UEFI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301872/problem-while-changing-the-sata-mode-to-ahci?noredirect=1#comment2213148_1301872
 And many Acer require "trust" Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot