# Dual boot: Windows10 only boots in RAID On mode while Ubuntu only boots in AHCI mode

Tags: dual-boot, raid, ahci, rst

I bought a new laptop Dell - Latitude - 9410 2 in 1 with Windows 10. I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS wich is my main OS. I want use the two OS with a dual boot.
In what follows I describe different steps of the attempt I done, knowing that the laptop is coming with Windows 10 Pro preinstalled. (Main reference : [Dell support](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/fr-ma/000132108/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-vista-or-7-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en))

1. I tried Ubuntu by using Live USB. It works.
2. I started the installation which has asked to disable the **RST mode** (I disabled the icone RAID On in the Bios)
3. I made some changes in the Registry Editor (cf: [Registry Editor](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347))
4. I choose the mode AHCI instead **RAID On** in the Bios (Bios -> Systeme Configuration -> Sata Operation)
5. As required by the installation, **I disabled the BitLocker** in Windows.

At each step, I had to interrupt the installation and then go back to Windows or Bios to make the required changes. As you see, It was long and complicated.

**Result**: I succeeded to install Linux, but there is a problem in the boot: **If the mode AHCI is enabled in the Bios, Ubuntu works but not Windows. If the mode RAID On is enabled in the Bios, Windows works but not Ubuntu**.
I think I am close to the objective but I don't know how to do get around the described difficulty of the boot.
Someone would have an idea?
Thank you for your help

Comment: As always, you need to install AHCI support in Windows and you need to boot Windows in that mode to confirm it's working and eventually let it run chkdsk. Also disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: BTW, please correct the title.

Comment: Thank you. It was corrected.

Comment: Windows AHCI instructions - some have found safeboot method better
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
But if you do a safe boot first, then boot to UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI and finally boot normally, it works
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Comment: Wonderful! It works! I used the second choice suggested in [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems). Thank you very much