# Cannot get to GRUB menu on dual boot

Tags: boot

I have successfully created dual boot windows 10 + Ubuntu on previous machines but I cannot figure it out on my new laptop.

Laptop: ASUS Q537
OS: Windows 10 home

Method: Download Ubuntu 20.04 to live USB and boot from USB

Ubuntu installation:

1. I choose the last option of "something else" and select the free space from the menu.
2. Installation goes well and ubuntu install.
3. Reboot and there is no option for ubuntu in UEFI settings.
4. boot-repair has not worked

Basically, I install ubuntu but never can get to a GRUB menu unless I boot from USB. I have looked at many threads but cant seem to figure it out. Can anyone help? What other information do you need?

I have tried Installing Ubuntu "alongside" Windows as well(as opposed to selecting the "something else" option in the ubuntu installer menu. Neither approach brings me to a GRUB menu on reboot.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r8hmKqWjBG/

Holding ESC on reboot gives me this

[boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkqA3.jpg)

Comment: @Nmath I have Ubuntu installed. After installation I restart my computer and it boots directly to Windows without a menu for me to select which OS i would like to boot into.

Comment: @Nmath updated original post with image of boot menu I receive while holding ESC key

Comment: No problem
1. Yes, but only from live USB. If the USB is not connected, I cannot get into Ubuntu.
2. UEFI
2a. I believe so? The device I click in UEFI settings is "UEFI: sandisk etc etc etc"
3. Yes, this is disabled.

Comment: It doesn't seem like Ubuntu is actually installed. It's essential that the Ubuntu installation media must boot in the same mode as Windows is installed. If Windows is installed as MBR/BIOS/Compatibility you must do the same for Ubuntu. You need to figure this out definitively

Comment: What else can confirm Ubuntu installation besides a success message (and request to reboot) + an Ubuntu terminal command lsb_release -a responding with a readout of Ubuntu 20.04? I am confident both my version of Windows and Ubuntu boot are UEFI.

Comment: how are you able to run any commands if you cannot boot into Ubuntu?  From the live session?  That gives information about the live session, not your installation.  You can boot the live session after installation and look in the "disks" application to see if there is actually a Ubuntu partition and where it's located

Comment: It looks like you still have drive in RAID or Intel RST mode. It needs to be AHCI for Ubuntu to see drive. And then Windows fast start up must be off. You also have grub installed to MBR, so that would not be from an UEFI install. Be sure to boot in UEFI mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state

Comment: Ok, I switched to AHCI. I have Secure Boot enabled. I have fast boot disabled. I will go through Ubuntu installation process again.

Comment: Issue solved! The ACHI + selecting the top level device for boot loader installation was the problem. I ended up selecting /dev/nvme0n1 instead of what the tutorials were suggesting. Thank you.

Comment: Consider posting the details of your solution as an answer below so that this question can be helpful for future visitors with the same question.