# Boot problems after trying to install Ubuntu (dual boot w Windows)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

Like the title states, I was attempting to install Ubuntu as a dual os alongside windows. I was able to download it onto a USB drive and was able to boot Ubuntu from it ok.

After a couple of uses I wanted to actually install it on my pc alongside Windows. Everything was going well until I ran into and Intel RST issue that prevented me from being able to install it.

I followed the instructions from: https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

I came across the boot problems mentioned in the instructions. I followed the steps to repair but when I go enter ‘disk part’ and list the volumes, there is not one that shows for Windows. I assume that it would be letter C but it has no label so I am unsure. When I try to select and set C as active it gives me the following : “The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk. The active command can only be used on fixed MBR disks”.

Any tips would be helpful, thanks in advanced!

Comment: The following images may help:

https://imgur.com/a/c4SddeC

Comment: Did you install AHCI drivers into WIndows first? Windows AHCI instructions - some have found safeboot method better
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems  And is Windows fast startup/hibernation off? What brand/model system? Some require extra settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting GRUB to be the default bootloader instead of Windows Boot Manager and see if that helps with the issue. There's a great instructional guide found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-to-get-grub-to-be-the-default-bootloader-instead-of-windows-boot-manager-on). He mentions having Ubuntu installed first. I personally had Win10 installed first on my system and it still worked without any issues for me.