# Ubuntu installer not detecting windows 10

Tags: windows-10, 21.04

I have treid everything from disabling secure boot to fixing the drive, is there a way for it to detect windows or just a way for it to dual boot without it detecting it

Comment: Tell us a little more about your setup.  What machine model, and was Windows installed by the vendor or from an upgrade from Windows 7 (Trying to figure out if in legacy mode or UEFI).  Most likely, you are booting the Ubuntu installer (depends upon your machine settings) in the other mode from windows.

Comment: Is Windows fast start up off? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Did you change from RAID or Intel RST to AHCI? But you must install AHCI drivers into Windows first. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems

Comment: @oldfred did both of those, still does not work

Comment: If using 21.04 it is EoL or expired. You need to use a current version. And answer ubfan1's questions. https://ubuntu.com/download

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.