# Why is the installer stopping with RST error before I have a chance to choose an external drive for the install?

Tags: system-installation, raid, rst

The installer prevents me from proceeding with the following install:

- Dell Precision 3541 laptop, with internal SSD w/ Windows 10, and an internal traditional hard drive for data
- Bootable USB flash drive with Ubuntu 22.04 - Budgie iso
- Samsung T7 external SSD drive

I am booting into Ubuntu Live DVD off of the flash drive. I intend to install Ubuntu on the external SSD drive, but the installer detects that RST is enabled on the laptop. I don't see why it's stopping me from installing - I wasn't going to install onto the laptop. In addition, the laptop doesn't use RAID. I have two separate individual drives, a "C" drive and a "D" drive, but I did confirm that RST is enabled in BIOS.

Note that the Samsung T7 already has two Linux distros installed on it (MX & Fedora), and I did them both without any of this RST business happening. So I don't get it.

Is there a way to force the installer past the RST check, and if so is it safe to proceed to install Ubuntu on the external SSD?

Comment: I installed to my Dell 5310 with RAID on & Secure Boot on. I did have to turn off Windows bitlocker & fast startup. It used VMD driver, not the AHCI driver. sudodus -In a Dell Latitude 3520 Windows is installed with RST, and installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS alongside it without changing any setting in the UEFI/BIOS system.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411848/nvme-vs-ahci-speed-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu
 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543006&p=14097006#post14097006
 But if installing to external drive  see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: @oldfred Thanks. That launchpad post is a bit scary, but I note that it's an older post. Maybe I'll wait until they fix this. I don't want to take a chance on messing up Windows; that's why I put my Linuxes on the external drive. (I used to dual boot back in the old days before UEFI.)

Comment: I have posted since 2014 waiting for them to fix the Ubiquity issue. They now are testing a new installer and I bet they are not doing much on Ubiquity now. I installed Kubuntu 23.04 a month ago which still used Ubiquity and issue is still there. Multiple work arounds posted in bug report. If you have an ESP on external drive easy to fix. Or this which is one of posts in bug report. https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator  My work around a bit more complex.