# "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/nvme0n1" when installing Ubuntu 22 along Windows 10 Home on HP Envy x360

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to dual boot my HP envy x360 with 512 GBs of SSD and Windows 10 Home already installed. I created a bootable USB using Rufus and put Ubuntu 22.04 on it.

I also disabled Secure Boot from my BIOS settings.

BIOS Boot Options:

[image: BIOS Boot Options (shows that Secure Boot is off)]

I disabled bitlocker and decrypted my C drive, I also shrank the C drive to create some unallocated space.

[image: disk manager showing bitlocker is off and there is about 70Gbs of unallocated space]

I have the following storage controllers:
[!device manager showing RST storage controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THl8w.png)

I then rebooted my laptop from the USB using the "change advanced startup options" of windows, I will include the steps below:

[image: booting from USB part 2]

(I chose the "EFI USB device option")

I then chose the "Install Ubuntu" option and chose normal installation. When asked where to install Ubuntu, I chose the *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager* option:

[image: installation type page]

The installation started and the progress bar was filled until near the end, when I got this Error:
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/nvme0n1:
executing 'grub-install /dev/nvme0n1' failed.
this is a fatal error.

[image: Picture of the error message]

I was asked to restart the computer, after which windows was loaded.

Other ways I have tried:

1. I chose the "something else" option on the installation type and mounted 3 GBs as the /root directory and mounted the rest of the free space I had created on windows as the root (/) directory. the rest of the options were left unchanged, this is a picture of the partitioning screen.

[image: partitioning page]

After trying to install, I got the same error as before, but Ubuntu was installed on my drive as the next time I tried to run the installer, I was given the option to *Erase and reinstall Ubuntu*.

2. I again chose the "something else" option and this time only the / directory to the free space and set the "Device for bootloader installation" to the partition marked as "Windows Boot Manager". I tried installing again and got the same error.
3. I burned another version (Ubuntu 20.04) onto the USB and tried installing using the *Something else* option and got the same error.

I would be glad to share any info/screenshots that would clarify the problem.

I got a Boot Info Summary using Boot-Repair and got this pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DZdJGBshsP/

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi

md/imsm0: ______________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3
OS#2:   Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on nvme0n1p5

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] GP108M [GeForce MX330] from Intel Corporation NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F.24(15.24) from Insyde
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled - SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,3001,2002,2004
Boot0000* USB Hard Drive (UEFI) - General USB Flash Disk (General USB Flash Disk)   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(0,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x18d8d7,0x800,0x1dd9000)RC
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,14b3b884-38b7-4d46-93f7-ea16b411282c,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC

de3ee3ac3e402dfb9f2cb2b38d215225   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
d9c4ec54a5e4fff17ea5ca059dee9416   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt32.efi
659a6171d178c951211c4868fccbfa9b   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi
1b8c0684ede8539ccc205cf7a750eca3   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA32.efi
6488d391f74263c9da3c3d47dffa6212   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi
6d6c99b06136830bbc041fe57b04f658   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/HpBiosMgmt.efi
6488d391f74263c9da3c3d47dffa6212   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi
9ca774eb2290dce4f276eaec4aced423   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi
72293f4ecf0f5b24dce601d2c3c4b26e   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
75641ea3cae97c7ea935e501d6e5e227   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme1n1 : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 9B6B322A-E01A-48C4-BAA5-86025779ADA6
              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    567296  855754751 855187456 407.8G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 999116800 1000198143   1081344   528M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 855754752  999116799 143362048  68.4G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk nvme1n1: 27.25 GiB, 29260513280 bytes, 57149440 sectors
Disk sda: 14.92 GiB, 16025387008 bytes, 31299584 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0018d8d7
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 31299583 31297536 14.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:16.0GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:General USB Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:16.0GB:16.0GB:fat32::boot, lba;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:INTEL HBRPEKNX0202AH:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:438GB:438GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:438GB:512GB:73.4GB:ext4::;
4:512GB:512GB:554MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
nvme1n1:29.3GB:nvme:512:512:unknown:INTEL HBRPEKNX0202AHO:;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE          UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL            PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                    
└─sda1      vfat            706B-8706                            0018d8d7-01                          UBUNTU 22_0      
nvme0n1     isw_raid_member                                                                                            
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat            B439-C902                            14b3b884-38b7-4d46-93f7-ea16b411282c SYSTEM           EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                                      0d52444b-83ce-4acc-9ad6-e9d1793b3caf                  Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs            D072752072750C8A                     4a6dbb08-0a42-4e83-93c8-575223ff2e5e Windows          Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs            B4A21A18A219E022                     f8471a8e-ada5-4520-865b-7de240c6cbf4 Windows RE tools Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4            7a62fc8e-de21-4c0f-8850-2fa855cf0c02 d7f44e53-cab5-458b-a31e-aebab9ef178a                  
nvme1n1     isw_raid_member                                                                                            
└─md127                                                                                                                

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1         173.7M  32% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3         134.7G  67% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4          67.7M  87% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5          54.8G  13% /target
/dev/sda1               11.5G  23% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1         vfat            ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p5         ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

=================== blkid (filtered) before raid activation ====================

/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="B439-C902" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="14b3b884-38b7-4d46-93f7-ea16b411282c"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="Windows" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="D072752072750C8A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="4a6dbb08-0a42-4e83-93c8-575223ff2e5e"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="Windows RE tools" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="B4A21A18A219E022" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f8471a8e-ada5-4520-865b-7de240c6cbf4"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="7a62fc8e-de21-4c0f-8850-2fa855cf0c02" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d7f44e53-cab5-458b-a31e-aebab9ef178a"
/dev/nvme1n1: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="UBUNTU 22_0" UUID="706B-8706" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0018d8d7-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="0d52444b-83ce-4acc-9ad6-e9d1793b3caf"


==================================== dmraid ====================================

dmraid -si -c
no block devices found
dmraid -ay:
no block devices found
dmraid -sa -c:
no block devices found


==================================== mdadm =====================================
mdadm --assemble --scan

mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/imsm0 metadata=imsm UUID=d4920e23:0470b5fb:00ee1f05:61a19535


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to enable-raid) and reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p5,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

/target detected. Please close the Ubuntu installer, then retry. 

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
```

Comment: Do you have Optane or RAID setting on Drive, not AHCI. I thought it would not even install, but now maybe it is just grub? Is Windows fast start up off? That is different than UEFI fast boot. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I just did as you asked, I reinstalled (erased and then reinstalled) ubuntu and after the error popup, I did not restart, but rather entered the live OS (I think). I ran the commands in the terminal and got a bootinfo and uploaded the report to a pastebin, this is the link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DZdJGBshsP/
I'm not sure how to check if AHCI is on, I would appreciate more info on that. windows fast start up is off(I included a screen shot in the original question).
@oldfred

Comment: Fast start up is different than fast boot. You said it was fast boot screen shot but is fast start up. Fast boot is an UEFI setting and assumes no system changes. Best to be off while changing system. You also show RAID on NVMe drives which means your Intel RST or RAID setting in UEFI is still on. You first must install AHCI drivers into Windows or it will not boot once you change to AHCI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

Comment: I read the articles you posted, and all of them say that if RST is creating problems the Ubuntu installer will throw an error and ask that the system be turned off. I never got such an error and that was kind of strange.
Nevertheless, I will change to AHCI and cross my fingers...
Let's see what happens!'

Comment: I can't seem to change the controller on bios. I went to
Configuration->UEFI HII Config->Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology->Intel Optane Volume 477Gb->Disable
and it disabled optane(I guess). If I choose my drive, an info page opens that says its status is "non-RAID" and its controller type is NVME. I find no other option for changing storage controllers in my BIOS.I have edited the question to include a screenshot of my device manager so you can see my storage controllers.
Any suggestions/workarounds at this point would be much appreciated. And should I try boot repair from linux? @oldfred

Comment: If just NVMe does grub install? the NVMe driver is actually separate, but many systems have had both a NVMe drive and a SATA drive. I have both NVMe & SATA so have AHCI on. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive/NVMe But Optane is a unique NVMe device, so not sure if drive works just as NVMe. Often Optane device is a second small drive and some users have just unplugged it or replaced with a larger NVMe drive.Intel just announced they were discontinuing Optane. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474790

Answer (score 1):

In your Bios boot manager under the Boot menu,pick Add drive. Look for your Ubuntu partition drive, in there the boot directory and then the ESI file. Add that. Should load the grub boot menu. I just did this to restore my dual boot after Windows upgrade zapped that and went straight into windows. Now grub works again