# Unable to install GRUB in /dev/nvme0n1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, boot-repair

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 as dual boot in my laptop and I've been having some trouble.

I have a hp pavillion, with windows 11. I've just formatted my laptop, installed everything again. I've made a 50GB partition in my disk, on which I plan to install Ubuntu. I've flashed a USB drive using Rufus and the ISO file from the Ubuntu website. I've changed the boot order in the BIOS interface to prioritize the USB drive, I've also disabled Secure Boot.

I boot my computer with the USB drive connected and all goes well, I go into the Linux installation process, I choose normal installation, check the third party thing, and the one to download stuff while installing. I then choose the manual partition option, I create a swap partition of 4GB (swap option), and create a root partition (ext4 and "/"). I then continue. The installation begins, all goes well until near the end when it stops and shows this error: `Unable to install GRUB in /dev/nvme0n1: executing grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 failed. this is a fatal error`. Here it fails.

I've tried booting into the Linux live session and installing Boot-Repair, and running it and doing the recommended repair, to which another error appears: `/target detected. Please close the Ubuntu installer, then retry`.

I ran the Boot-Repair analysis and got this pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b6DXbpmwvg/

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT16
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda2 starts 
                       at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sda2 starts at sector 15238408. According to the info 
                       in the boot sector, sda2 has 0 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootaa64.efi /efi/Boot/bootarm.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/bootia32.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Rufus/exfat_aa64.efi /efi/Rufus/exfat_arm.efi 
                       /efi/Rufus/exfat_ia32.efi /efi/Rufus/exfat_x64.efi 
                       /efi/Rufus/ntfs_aa64.efi /efi/Rufus/ntfs_arm.efi 
                       /efi/Rufus/ntfs_ia32.efi /efi/Rufus/ntfs_x64.efi

md/imsm0: ______________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

md/imsm1: ______________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Iris Plus Graphics G7 from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F.30(15.30) from AMI
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,794dca7b-e5b4-414b-9824-1de042ba7e67,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,794dca7b-e5b4-414b-9824-1de042ba7e67,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...&................
Boot0002* Internal Hard Disk    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(6144,32768,1)/HD(1,GPT,794dca7b-e5b4-414b-9824-1de042ba7e67,0x800,0x82000)..BO
Boot0003* USB Drive (UEFI) -  USB Flash MemoryPMAP  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(2,GPT,3ce2f0f9-7591-4ff9-9173-994724c1c9e8,0xe88508,0x800)..BO

e099b8f8463ef839720fda267e70eeb1   sda2/Boot/bootaa64.efi
cfd0ce50df258fc747f5753ecf6ec312   sda2/Boot/bootarm.efi
19a65a943434a625a53490391fa28349   sda2/Boot/bootia32.efi
3fdfc83db7958b2eac1e720334f12147   sda2/Boot/bootx64.efi
4a4e8e66e0d3712f19d964a7bca4fafc   sda2/Rufus/exfat_aa64.efi
93f66a43d49990f986a81c67843d66a5   sda2/Rufus/exfat_arm.efi
3c5f23f198267df4a64fe2a3587039e7   sda2/Rufus/exfat_ia32.efi
81d015f35982a0bbf4056f09a2eca39a   sda2/Rufus/exfat_x64.efi
a03e27b0e7f2e03519166bf6b41f68c5   sda2/Rufus/ntfs_aa64.efi
2f31c70d3f4235476cd9ed6a18e13221   sda2/Rufus/ntfs_arm.efi
7e7e67c33ce9ff2961a4be4080d23352   sda2/Rufus/ntfs_ia32.efi
30c7e0752040cf5e31843d897a53e055   sda2/Rufus/ntfs_x64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme1n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: A7A91DE9-2963-4BF9-8E69-C1BE2BC06A1C
             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme1n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
nvme1n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme1n1p3    567296 393799455 393232160 187.5G Microsoft basic data
nvme1n1p4 498659328 500099071   1439744   703M Windows recovery environment
Disk nvme0n1: 13.41 GiB, 14403239936 bytes, 28131328 sectors
Disk sda: 7.27 GiB, 7803174912 bytes, 15240576 sectors
Disk identifier: 43B00A3D-D935-47FB-9FB6-7C8A900E8421
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sda1      2048 15238407 15236360  7.3G Microsoft basic data
sda2  15238408 15240455     2048    1M Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:7803MB:scsi:512:512:gpt: USB Flash Memory:;
1:1049kB:7802MB:7801MB:ntfs:Main Data Partition:msftdata;
2:7802MB:7803MB:1049kB::UEFI:NTFS:msftdata;
nvme0n1:14.4GB:nvme:512:512:unknown:INTEL HBRPEKNX0101AHO:;
nvme1n1:256GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:INTEL HBRPEKNX0101AH:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:202GB:201GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:255GB:256GB:737MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

nvme1n1: 192285MiB:243486MiB:51201MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME    FSTYPE          UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                        
├─sda1  ntfs            089C547D9C5466EA                     a928fc82-48a5-42a6-81c6-bbb0d2d47f12 Ubuntu 22_04_4 LTS amd64 Main Data Partition
└─sda2  vfat            5FA3-F2DA                            3ce2f0f9-7591-4ff9-9173-994724c1c9e8 UEFI_NTFS                UEFI:NTFS
nvme1n1 isw_raid_member                                                                                                    
└─md127                                                                                                                    
nvme0n1 isw_raid_member                                                                                                    
└─md126                                                                                                                    

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                           Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                   2.6G  65% /cdrom
/dev/sda2                   130K  87% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
efivarfs                  110.8K  40% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1                 fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda2                 vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sda


/dev/sda2: unknown GPT attributes
9000000000000000
Unknown BootLoader on md/imsm0

Unknown BootLoader on md/imsm1



=================== blkid (filtered) before raid activation ====================

/dev/nvme0n1: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="A20A-FDA4" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="794dca7b-e5b4-414b-9824-1de042ba7e67"
/dev/nvme1n1p3: LABEL="Windows" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="1CEE539DEE536DD0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f11520f9-3994-4bb1-ad3e-eb725513d0e8"
/dev/nvme1n1p4: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="E80CF4D40CF49EAE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5710657f-a947-4111-84ce-bb82bd7dd40e"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Ubuntu 22_04_4 LTS amd64" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="089C547D9C5466EA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Main Data Partition" PARTUUID="a928fc82-48a5-42a6-81c6-bbb0d2d47f12"
/dev/sda2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="UEFI_NTFS" LABEL="UEFI_NTFS" UUID="5FA3-F2DA" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="UEFI:NTFS" PARTUUID="3ce2f0f9-7591-4ff9-9173-994724c1c9e8"
/dev/nvme1n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="21abd4cd-420d-466d-b0cf-af511a0654b6"


==================================== dmraid ====================================

dmraid -si -c
no block devices found
dmraid -ay:
no block devices found
dmraid -sa -c:
no block devices found


==================================== mdadm =====================================
mdadm --assemble --scan

mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/imsm0 metadata=imsm UUID=9519726f:d304236b:940b8e71:c7330537
ARRAY /dev/md/imsm1 metadata=imsm UUID=b71614e7:dd893aee:cda51236:c3f3f731
Successfully activated RAID.


==================== blkid (filtered) after raid activation ====================

/dev/nvme0n1: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Ubuntu 22_04_4 LTS amd64" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="089C547D9C5466EA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Main Data Partition" PARTUUID="a928fc82-48a5-42a6-81c6-bbb0d2d47f12"
/dev/sda2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="UEFI_NTFS" LABEL="UEFI_NTFS" UUID="5FA3-F2DA" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="UEFI:NTFS" PARTUUID="3ce2f0f9-7591-4ff9-9173-994724c1c9e8"
/dev/nvme1n1: TYPE="isw_raid_member"

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

Comment: Ubuntu supports Secure Boot under the default Secure Boot settings, as is most major Linux distributions.

Comment: You are showing two NVMe drives. And wants to install to first one. But both are shown as RAID. And nvme0n1 is only 13.4GB, or typical of Intel Optane. Optane is now obsolete. But Microsoft required a fast boot only cache to make boot seem faster. You probably need to turn RAID off, change to AHCI, and install AHCI drivers into Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems  Windows AHCI instructions - some have found safeboot method better